# Android Volley request with Google API Key restrictions

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-volley, youtube-data-api, google-console-developer

I request data from the YouTube Data API in my Android application.
This is working but I want to make sure that my key can only be used by my application, to do this you can add the package name and sha1 fingerprint of your app in the Google Developer console to restrict the usage of the API key to my apps.

Since I am using Volley to make the requests it seems that the fingerprint and package name are not send with the request and therefore all API requests made get an error.

How do make Volley send the package name and sha1 fingerprint to authenticate my request from the YouTube data API?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube Data API already has a client library for Android/Java, there's no need to use Volley to handle HTTP requests for YouTube.

If Volley is still needed, you may need to pass the appropriate API along with a Browser API key. That way, you still utilized Volley; but this will return a JSONObject instead of library objects like on the client library.

Comment: This answer is wrong, the client library not make 5% of the API Youtube really can make, such as getting video snippets from a playlist.

The only thing the client library can do is play the videos and pause / play / next / previous